# Is there a better way to determine a method's behaviour than by passing it parameters?

Tags: java, function-pointers, strategy-pattern

Minimal working example:

```
static void foo(boolean bar){
   some code A
   if(bar){
      some code B
   }
   else{
      some code C
   }
   some code D
}
```

Here we use the parameter bar to determine the method's behavior, not to actually do something with its value. As a result we redundantly check the value of `bar`. The method that calls `foo()` *knows* the value of `bar`, since it actually passed it as a parameter. A simple alternative would be:

```
static void foo1(){
   A;B;D;
}

static void foo2(){
A;C;D
}
```

The result is, that we have redundant code. Now we could put A and D into methods, but what if they manipulate several variables? Java doesn't have methods with multiple return types. Even assuming we *could* put them into methods, we would still have `foo1` looking like `a();b();d()`, and `foo2` looking like `a();c();d()`. My current solution to this issue is create a functional interface for `c(), b()` , then to define foo as

```
static void foo(BCinterface baz){ A; baz.do() ;D;}
```

The issue is that every time I want to write a method with slightly different behaviors, I have to define an interface for the methods where they differ. I know in other languages there are function pointers. Is there any way to achieve something similar in java without having to define an interface every time? Or is there some practice to avoid having these kinds of situations come up in the first place?

Comment: If java starts defining functional interfaces with more than one methods then whole Lambda Expression will fall.  Because Lambda expressions can only work with the interfaces which have only one method to be over ridden. If it creates two, then there is no way to differentiate between those two methods by only the lambda expression.

Comment: I think choice of using `static` is the root of problems here. If it were class instance methods, this situation is easily solvable with a template pattern or strategy pattern.

Comment: You can use an anonymous class implementing Runnable as a parameter - the plain old Java 7 way.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior?newreg=6f3e1f96f4654cde80e25d16374fe0e8 seems to be what I was wondering about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I think your very first code snippet is the best and most readable solution.

`bar` is used to determine what the method will do, so what? Why try to move this logic to the caller of `foo`? There is no point. If I were trying to read the caller of `foo`, do I need to know how `foo` works (given it's well named)? No. Because I'm only interested in what happens in the caller of `foo`. Abstraction is a *good* thing, not a bad thing. So my advice is, leave it as that.

If you really want to extract the logic, you don't need a new functional interface every time. The `java.util.function` package and `java.lang` package already provides you with some functional interfaces. Just use them. For example, in your specific case, `BCInterface` can be replaced by `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks, The built in interfaces using Generics are just what I need! I understand your issue with knowing the implementation of `foo`, the only other alternative would be to have differently named functions to call on every level, which would then internally perform this behavior. like: foo1, foo2, foo1 = foo_internal(pattern1), foo_internal(BCInterface pattern)={A;pattern.do();D;}, pattern1 = ->{B;}

Answer (score 0):

Your way of solving duplicated invocations seems over complicated.
To provide a distinct behavior at a specific step of an processing/algorithm, you can simply use [the template method pattern](http://In%20software%20engineering,%20the%20template%20method%20pattern%20is%20a%20behavioral%20design%20pattern%20that%20defines%20the%20program%20skeleton%20of%20an%20algorithm%20in%20an%20operation,%20deferring%20some%20steps%20to%20subclasses.[1]%20It%20lets%20one%20redefine%20certain%20steps%20of%20an%20algorithm%20without%20changing%20the%20algorithm's%20structure.[2]) that relies on abstract method(s)s and polymorphism :

> In software engineering, the template method pattern is a behavioral
>   design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in an
>   operation, deferring some steps to subclasses.[1](http://In%20software%20engineering,%20the%20template%20method%20pattern%20is%20a%20behavioral%20design%20pattern%20that%20defines%20the%20program%20skeleton%20of%20an%20algorithm%20in%20an%20operation,%20deferring%20some%20steps%20to%20subclasses.[1]%20It%20lets%20one%20redefine%20certain%20steps%20of%20an%20algorithm%20without%20changing%20the%20algorithm's%20structure.[2]) It lets one redefine
>   certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's
>   structure.[2]

Of course you will have to remove all these `static` modifiers that don't allow to take advantage of OOP features.
The `boolean` parameter is not required either any longer.

Define in a base class `Foo`, `foo()` that defines the general behavior that relies on an abstract method and let the subclass to define the abstract method implementation.

```
public abstract class Foo{

    public abstract void specificBehavior();   

    public void foo(){
       a();
       specificBehavior();
       d();
    }

   public void a(){
      ...
   }

   public void d(){
      ...
   }

}
```

Now subclasses :

```
public class  FooOne extends Foo {
  public void specificBehavior(){
      ...
  }
}

public class FooTwo extends Foo {
  public void specificBehavior(){
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Which would be called `template pattern` if the `specific behaviour` was protected. Using `strategy pattern` (composition instead of inheritance) can be more desirable, e.g. when there is more than one aspect of variation